# How do you calculate a probability of at least one success with fractional attempts?

Tags: probability

I want to find out the efficiency of various experiments.  Let's say I need at least one success to win with three different options:

```
Cost     Attempts    Odds per roll
 $1        5              50%
 $2        2.5            75%
 $5        1            96.875%
```

We know the first and third are equivalent by calculating what the odds of rolling 50% five times using Bernoulli.

To compare the first and second one, we would have to calculate what the odds of rolling 75% 2.5 times.  Can we just do $1 - (1 - .75)^{2.5}$, or do we have to do something different?

Comment: This will likely depend on the exact meaning of a "fractional attempt". What does it mean to roll 0.5 times? Can you get half a success on half a roll?

Comment: I guess I'm just using attempts as a proxy for the ratio of cost.  Since \$5 is 2.5x more than \$2, what do the odds of success have to be for their value to be equivalent.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Hmm.. I sort of understand but I don't think this is enough explanation to answer sufficiently. In order to make progress, I think it is required to explicitly relate successes to (fractional) attempts. Otherwise, we have no way to understand how to apply the odds of success.